# Replacing strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, function

I have a function below and also the output, it is basically to find particular letters in a string and replace them with some other letters, for example in this string `abcde` I want to replace `de` with `xy`, so I give `@input = abcde`, `@find = de` and `@replace = xy`, so I get the output as `abcxy`, but if assume I have a string `hat` and I want to replace `h` and `t` with `m` and `c`, how do i achieve this?

And I must find the solution without using a while loop in my function

```
create  FUNCTION dbo.replace_letters
(
  @Input AS VarChar(1000),
  @Find AS VarChar(100),
  @Replace AS VarChar(100)
)
RETURNS VarChar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @Input = REPLACE(@Input, @Find,@Replace)

   return @input
end

--run
select dbo.replace_letters ('abcde', 'ed', 'dc')
```

Comment: Why do you need a function? why not directly use the replace function? what is the problem you can not solve? it sounds it work and looks good? why not just call the replace function for all replacements you need to perform?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is, to run the function a second time :-)

```
select dbo.replace_letters(dbo.replace_letters('hat', 'h', 'm'), 't', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply run

select REPLACE(REPLACE ('HAT','H','M'),'T','C').

SQL Server provides the replace function then why to write your own for doing same task ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
It will replace first character from @Find and replace it with first character of @Replace and second character from @Find and replace it with second character of @Replace.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION dbo.replace_letters
(
  @Input AS VARCHAR(1000),
  @Find AS VARCHAR(100),
  @Replace AS VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @Input = REPLACE(REPLACE(@Input, SUBSTRING(@Find,1,1),SUBSTRING(@Replace,1,1)),SUBSTRING(@Find,2,1),SUBSTRING(@Replace,2,1))
   RETURN @input
END

 SELECT dbo.replace_letters('hat','ht','mc')
 SELECT dbo.replace_letters('hahtaahtat','ht','xy')
```

ANSWER IS :

mac

xaxyaaxyay